# create rows from database column

Tags: python, sql, mariadb, pivot-table

currently i have this data retrieved from database as follows,

```
+------------+--------------+-------+-----+-------------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
    | Monitor ID | Casting Date | Label | AGE | Client Name |  Project  | Average Strength | Average Density |
    +------------+--------------+-------+-----+-------------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
    |    1082    |  2018-07-05  |  b52  |  1  |  Trial Mix  | Trial Mix |      21.78       |      2.436      |
    |    1082    |  2018-07-05  |  b52  |  2  |  Trial Mix  | Trial Mix |      33.11       |      2.406      |
    |    1082    |  2018-07-05  |  b52  |  4  |  Trial Mix  | Trial Mix |      43.11       |      2.447      |
    |    1082    |  2018-07-05  |  b52  |  8  |  Trial Mix  | Trial Mix |      48.22       |      2.444      |
    |    1083    |  2018-07-05  |  B53  |  1  |  Trial Mix  | Trial Mix |      10.44       |      2.421      |
    |    1083    |  2018-07-05  |  B53  |  2  |  Trial Mix  | Trial Mix |       20.0       |      2.400      |
    |    1083    |  2018-07-05  |  B53  |  4  |  Trial Mix  | Trial Mix |      27.78       |      2.397      |
    |    1083    |  2018-07-05  |  B53  |  8  |  Trial Mix  | Trial Mix |      33.33       |      2.409      |
    |    1084    |  2018-07-05  |  B54  |  1  |  Trial Mix  | Trial Mix |      12.89       |      2.430      |
    |    1084    |  2018-07-05  |  B54  |  2  |  Trial Mix  | Trial Mix |      24.44       |      2.427      |
    |    1084    |  2018-07-05  |  B54  |  4  |  Trial Mix  | Trial Mix |      34.22       |      2.412      |
    |    1084    |  2018-07-05  |  B54  |  8  |  Trial Mix  | Trial Mix |      41.56       |      2.501      |
    +------------+--------------+-------+-----+-------------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
```

how can i change the table to something like this?

```
    +------------+--------------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+
| Monitor Id | Casting Date | Label |  Client   |  Project  |  1 Day  |             | 2 Days  |             | 4 Days  |             | 8 Days  |             |
+------------+--------------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+
|            |              |       |           |           | avg str | avg density | avg str | avg density | avg str | avg density | avg str | avg density |
|            |              |       |           |           |         |             |         |             |         |             |         |             |
|       1082 | 05/07/2018   | B52   | Trial Mix | Trial Mix | 21.78   | 2.436       | 33.11   | 2.406       | 43.11   | 2.44        | 48.22   | 2.444       |
|       1083 | 05/07/2018   | B53   | Trial Mix | Trial Mix | 10.44   | 2.421       | 20      | 2.4         | 27.78   | 2.397       | 33.33   | 2.409       |
|       1084 | 05/07/2018   | B54   | Trial Mix | Trial Mix | 12.89   | 2.43        | 24.44   | 2.427       | 34.22   | 2.412       | 41.56   | 2.501       |
+------------+--------------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+
```

i get the data by joining multiple table from the database using peewee
below is my full code to retrieve and format the data

```
from lib.database import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from prettytable import PrettyTable
import numpy as np

#table to hold data
table = PrettyTable()
table.field_names = ['Monitor ID','Casting Date','Label','AGE','Client Name','Project', 'Average Strength','Average Density']

#interval of 2 weeks ago
int = datetime.today()-timedelta(days=14)

result = MonitorCombine.select(ResultCombine.strength.alias('str'),ResultCombine.density.alias('density'),ResultCombine.age,MonitorCombine.clientname,MonitorCombine.p_alias,MonitorCombine.monitorid, MonitorCombine.monitor_label,MonitorCombine.casting_date).join(ResultCombine, on=(ResultCombine.monitorid == MonitorCombine.monitorid)).dicts().where(MonitorCombine.casting_date > int).order_by(MonitorCombine.monitor_label,ResultCombine.age.asc())

for r in result: table.add_row([r['monitorid'],r['casting_date'],r['monitor_label'],r['age'],r['clientname'],r['p_alias'],r['str'],r['density']])
print(table)
```

Comment: What is the logic behind each of the day columns?  I might try to handle this in the database.  By the way, which database are you using?

Comment: i am using MariaDb. the Day(age) are calculated by the database based on the date of testing and casting date. so the age are not manually update but has its own column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pivot the data, since MariaDB has no pivot you could do it in sql:

```
SELECT
    MonitorID,
    CastingDate,
    Label,
    ClientName,
    Project,
    SUM(IF(Age=1, AverageStrength, 0)) AS AvgStr1,
    SUM(IF(Age=2, AverageStrength, 0)) AS AvgStr2,
    SUM(IF(Age=4, AverageStrength, 0)) AS AvgStr4,
    SUM(IF(Age=8, AverageStrength, 0)) AS AvgStr8,
    SUM(IF(Age=1, AverageDensity, 0)) AS AvgDensity1,
    SUM(IF(Age=2, AverageDensity, 0)) AS AvgDensity2,
    SUM(IF(Age=4, AverageDensity, 0)) AS AvgDensity4,
    SUM(IF(Age=8, AverageDensity, 0)) AS AvgDensity8
FROM
    YourTable
GROUP BY MonitorID, CastingDate, Label, ClientName, Project, Age
ORDER BY MonitorID, CastingDate;
```